# CSS change style base on valid input

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I'm trying to style the asterisk ("*") inside the span element of a required field based on the "input:valid" property.

```
<apex:input value="{!firstName}" id="firstnameId" required="true" />
     <label class="lbStyle" for="FirstName"> First Name

      <span class="ddff" style="color:red;">*</span>

     </label>
```

I want to change the color of the "*" From Red to Green, If the input is valid.

How can I achive it using css?

I tried this :

```
input:valid .ddff {
      color: palegreen;
 }
```

But it not working.

I know I can do it in JS as well, but I have a lot of fields to change so I would like a css way if it is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually what I did is :

```
input:valid + label .ddff {
   color: palegreen;
}

.ddff{
   color: red;
}
```

And I removed the inline CSS in my span :

```
<apex:input value="{!firstName}" id="firstnameId" required="true" />
     <label class="lbStyle" for="FirstName"> First Name

      <span class="ddff">*</span>

     </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below css and html for your problem. It will work.

```
 <div class="input-wrapper">
    <apex:input id="firstnameId" required="true" />
     <label class="label" for="FirstName"> First Name</label>
    <span class="placeholder">*</span>
 </div>

 <style>
.input-wrapper input:invalid + .label + .placeholder {
  color:red;
}
  .input-wrapper input:valid + .label + .placeholder {
  color:palegreen;
}

 </style>
```

Comment: Hi, I want to change only the asterisk (*) inside the span - not the input.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I didn't test it, but it almost the same as the answer that I posted for this question - It's more readable I guess.
I'll give you an upvote for it thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom label put the custom label value * and use it this custom label on vfpage.

for eg:

```
 <span style="font-color:red;display:inline-block;"> {!$Label.**your_custom_label_name**} </span>
```